# MySQLi Multi Query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, multi-query

Good morning,

I am trying to use MySqli Multi-query to put variables that are posted by the login script in two different database tables; the common details need to be posted in the wp_users table, and the uncommon details need to be posted in the wp_users_info-table I've made myself.

I am trying to use the following code to do that:

```
       <?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
        $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);
        $achternaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['achternaam']);
        $upass = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']));
        $datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['datum']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $basisschool = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['basisschool']);
        $opleidingsduur = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['opleidingsduur']);
        $bsgroep = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bsgroep']);
        $url = '#leerling';
        $fullname = $uname . ' ' . $achternaam;

        if (mysqli_multi_query($con,"INSERT INTO wp_users (user_login,user_pass,user_nicename,user_email,user_url,user_registered,display_name) VALUES ('$email','$upass','$uname','$email','$url','now()','$fullname'); INSERT INTO wp_users_info (user_voornaam,user_achternaam,user_geboortedatum,user_basisschool,user_opleidingsduur,user_groep) VALUES('$uname','$achternaam','$datum','$basisschool','$opleidingsduur','$bsgroep')" )) {

            ?> <script>alert('Je hebt een account aangemaakt en vanaf nu kun je jezelf inloggen! ');</script><?php
            echo '<script>window.location = "' . $link2 . '";</script>';
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>alert('Fout bij het registreren...');</script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And if I run this code, I get the following errors:
[image]
Does anybody know how to use the code to make it work?

Sorry for my bad English, I'm from Holland.

Jeffrey

Comment: First of all learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: Looks like your db-connection is not established. can you Show where you call mysqli_connect?

Comment: I have a seperate file where I connect to the database.

Comment: db_connect.php, I require it at the beginning of the file. This is what's in:

Comment: <?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scoreplugin_db");

if(!$conn)
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>

Comment: And you call it in the same php file?

Comment: No, it is in a seperate php file, called db_connect.php. Do you think it is better to make the db connection in the same file?

Comment: Do you call this function you your php file?

Comment: I made the db connection in the same PHP file, and the errors are gone. But it only runs the first query. Do i use the multi query right?

Comment: yes the query is fine. but you have to create the Connection first. So you Need to incluse/require the function to connect to the db in your php file

Comment: I made the connection in the same php file now. When i send the form it now saves. But it only puts the data from the first query in the database. The second table that must be filled with the second query stays empty.

Comment: You can use two separate prepared queries to resolve the issue. Check my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two separate **prepared queries** like below:

```
// prepare and bind Users Query
$queryUsers = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_users(user_login,user_pass,user_nicename,user_email,user_url,user_registered,display_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$queryUsers->bind_param("sssssss",$email,$upass,$uname,$email,$url,$now,$fullname);

// execute Users Query
$queryUsers->execute();

// prepare and bind Users Info Query
$queryUsersInfo = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_users_info (user_voornaam,user_achternaam,user_geboortedatum,user_basisschool,user_opleidingsduur,user_groep) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$queryUsersInfo->bind_param("ssssss",$uname,$achternaam,$datum,$basisschool,$opleidingsduur,$bsgroep);

// execute Users Info Query
$queryUsersInfo->execute();

// Close Connections
$queryUsers->close();
$queryUsersInfo->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just DON'T use a multi query. That's not what you think it is.

Use **two separate prepared queries** for your inserts.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use it in my situation? Yesterday I was trying to make it work with two seperate queries but that didn't work also.